# How to compare filenames with partial match from a table or list

Tags: c#, .net, compare, string-comparison

I'm currently trying to code a simple tool to poll some files which arrive on a server at a designated time of night to confirm they have arrived and document any missing files. They will sit in this folder for approx. 40 minutes, then be moved out automatically via script (I have no control over this).

**My question is:**

How can I compare filenames for a partial match against a table (I want to match unique identifiers (`NUMBER` and `NUMBER2` below) in filename with those on a predefined table that the user can update via a Windows form). Presumably I want to split up the strings so I have split `NUMBER` and `NUMBER2` so I can compare these and see if they are included in the filename (*both* numbers must be included in the filename for it to be a match, and the order is significant).

**Filename format:**

> ```
> NCR_XR_D_NUMBER_NUMBER2
> ```

As order is significant, `NCR_XR_D_8003_9611` does not equal `NCR_XR_D_9611_8003`.

This is what I have right now:

```
public static void CheckIfFilesExist()
    {
        // Put all file names in XR File directory into array.

        string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@Properties.Settings.Default.XRFolderSavedLocation); 
        //this location is stored as a app setting, type: string, scope: User. This is tested working OK.

        // Print filenames into Console. (making sure the array is populating).
        Console.WriteLine("--- Files:---");

       foreach(string name in array1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: I can't see the problem here. Just loop all the files in `array1`,split by `_` and get the 3rd and 4th array elements to get both numbers...

Comment: `string[] fileNameItems = name.Split('_');` then you can get the last two items ie the numbers using `fileNameItems[fileNameItems.Length -1`] and look them up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a class to store the file path and the number part of the file name. Here I've joined the numbers together as it makes the comparison easy.

```
public class FileInfo
{
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }
    public string Numbers { get; private set; }

    public FileInfo(string filepath)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        if (!fileName.StartsWith("NCR"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong type of file.");
        }

        FilePath = filepath;

        var nameParts = fileName.Split('_');
        Numbers = nameParts[3] + nameParts[4];
    }
}
```

Then your function becomes:

```
    public static void CheckIfFilesExist()
    {
        var filesToFilter = Directory.GetFiles(@Properties.Settings.Default.XRFolderSavedLocation).Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
        var filterValues = GetFilterValues();

        var filteredFiles = filesToFilter.Where(f => filterValues.Contains(f.Numbers));
    }
```

Where `GetFilterValues()` returns an array of strings of the values you're looking for (e.g. `"80039611"`).

Comment: This is brilliant. The filter is a very elegant solution, i'l have to learn this inside out, i'm sure it'l be useful to me again.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this easily just by using `Split` on each file name. Something like:

```
public static void CheckIfFilesExist()
{
    string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@Properties.Settings.Default.XRFolderSavedLocation); 

    foreach(string name in array1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        if (Path.GetFileName(name).StartsWith("NCR"))
        {
             string[] splitted = name.Split('_');
             int number1 = int.Parse(splitted[3]);
             int number2 = int.Parse(splitted[4].Split('.')[0]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(number1);
        Console.WriteLine(number2);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! While I won't be using this particular solution, its great for helping me learn.